# How to determine angle to place people during a dolly in green screen if filmed separately?

Tags: measurement, compositing-nodes

I have a blender model of a large room.
In the scene, I have several people seated at consoles spread x feet apart (in reality, they are in a green screen studio).

I am using a physical chair for the individuals to sit in, to simplify compositing. The rest of the set is virtual in Blender. Because I don't want to buy multiple chairs for the shoot (they are all of a specific prop design, and not just general office chairs), I am shooting each person seated individually.

I want to do a slow dolly from right to left as an establishing shot in the scene. But I have to shoot each character individually in the green screen room, so they can use that same chair. I have a motorized unit to ensure the dolly moves are precise and consistent each shot. But, I am anticipating this move is still problematic because of parallax effect (desired look) during the dolly move.

I don't want to resort to just making the scene wide and animate sideways with the characters inserted into the scene (zero parallax), which is not a true dolly look. Even if I tried that, it wouldn't look natural without apparent rotation.

I know I have to do things like annotate lens focal length for each shot and whatnot. But, how do I determine the proper angle to place the individuals to make their positions appear to gradually differ as normal parallax effect would? Is some way of calculating the angle and distance to place them in relation to the camera available? Is this even possible without somehow having to rotate the the characters in place?

I learned how to measure distance from the locations in the blender model where the chairs should be. But, can I use this and any other measurement information to compute an angle to shoot each character and figure out a distance I can be from them to dolly the correct amount?

If the dolly move is impractical to pull off, even if I went to a backup plan to have a static establishing wide shot, what pitfalls am I looking at on how to make individually-shot persons appear to face the correct angle seated in front of the consoles in the model?

Thanks!